# How to show the right limit at $0$ of $\dfrac{1}{x \sin (\dfrac{1}{x})}$ does not exist?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I tried using sequential criteria for limits but don't know how to deal with $0+$ with sequences. Could you please give a hint?

Comment: Try looking for a positive sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ such that $x_n\to 0$ but $(x\sin (1/x))^{-1}$ shoots off to infinity.

Comment: what happens when $x = \frac{1}{n \pi}$  for integer $n \; \; ? \; \; $

Comment: To deal with $0+$, just take a *positive* sequence tending to zero.

Comment: @WillJagy $\dfrac{\infty}{0}$ as $n$ tends to infinity?

Comment: @HansLundmark got the point thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you can choose a decreasing sequence $x_n$ with $x_n\geq0$, $\lim_nx_n=0$, and $$\sin\frac1{x_n}=1,\qquad\qquad n\in\mathbb N.$$

Comment: $x_n = 2n\pi + \dfrac{\pi}{2} $ would do?

Comment: No, that doesn't go to zero nor is decreasing. The reciprocal works, though.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant $\dfrac{1}{x_n} = 2n\pi + \dfrac{\pi}{2} $

Comment: Yes, that's the natural choice.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: By the way can we say the function approach to infinity? if we take infinity as an extended real number?

Comment: If you want to be formal, you need to be careful when talking about infinity. In this case you don't need to talk about infinity at all. For your function, the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ is unbounded, which prevents it from converging.

Comment: So the right limit at $0$ does not exist even as an extended real number right?

Comment: when $x_n = \dfrac{1}{n\pi}$ $f(x_n)$ becomes undefined as $n$ tends to $\infty$. Thus certainly limit does not exist, I think

Comment: No, it doesn't. There are other choices of $x_n$ where the $f(x_n)$ will converge to a number, and others where it doesn't converge at all. A small tweak of your sequence to $x_n=1/(\pi/2+n\pi)$, now gives you $f(x_n)$ growing in absolute value but alternating signs.

Comment: Thank you so much got the exact idea

Comment: Glad I could help :)